# How to insert all arrays into an array with php without destroy my headers

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I read a csv file with my code and convert it into an array. 
This is my code:

```
$csv_data = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test123.csv'));
$csv_header = $csv_data[0];
unset($csv_data[0]);
foreach($csv_data as $row){
    $row = array_combine($csv_header, $row);
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($row);
    echo '<pre>';
}
```

And that's the output:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [article] => 000001
)

Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [article] => 000002
)
```

I'd like the arrays to be in an array, like this:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
     (
         [ID] => 1
         [article] => 000001
     )

     [1] => Array
     (
         [ID] => 2
         [article] => 000002
     )

)
```

Anybody got an idea? It's important that the headers don't get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$row = array_combine($csv_header, $row);
```

To

```
$rows[] = array_combine($csv_header, $row);
```

than use `print_r($rows)` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `&` to update array at its address.

```
foreach($csv_data as &$row){ // check & to update at its address
    $row = array_combine($csv_header, $row);
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($row);
    echo '<pre>';
}
print_r($csv_data); // you will get your expected data here
```